# Questions on frying Chicken breasts

Tags: chicken, frying, deep-frying, brining

Is the oil temperature limited to 350 or 375.
How do I Dry Brine chicken?
Is there a rule of thumb for how much seasoning is used?
Do I use more seasoning in the marinade than in the flour mixture?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Please use one question for each actual question you have. We can't answer so many questions at the same time. It will also help if you can flesh out each question more to explain what you've tried or why you're asking the question in the first place.

Comment: I *think* you might just have two questions here: (1) what oil temperature do you need and (2) how do you dry brine (including rough reasonable seasoning ratios).

Answer (score -1):

Brining chicken doesn't take more than an hour.Just make sure it is well dried before frying.  I use 1 pint of water with 1/8 cup of salt and the breast (which can be very dry when just fried) comes out juicy,  Hope this helps.
Seasoning should be coated with seasoning but be careful of the salt.  Brining adds some water to the breast but also some salt.

Comment: Using water and salt doesn't sound like "dry brining".

Comment: And why would you coat seasoning with seasoning?